# Filter Qt signals like one filters events

Tags: qt, events, pyqt, signals-slots

With Qt, I can filter all the `QEvent` events my application receives or produces with:

```
qApp.installEventFilter(my_filter_object)
```

Is there any way to filter Qt **signals** (of [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)) in a similar manner I can filter `QEvent` events?

With [`QtCore.QStateMachine.SignalEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstatemachine-signalevent.html) extending `QEvent`, and `StateMachineSignal` [`QEvent.Type`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qevent.html#Type-enum) being there, everything seems to be in place, but my event filter can't seem to catch one of these.

IOW, is there any way to get the signal's name (index), the signal emitting object, and the passed arguments, for each signal of every `QObject` in my application without explicitly connecting to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The only generic API for monitoring signals is [QSignalSpy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsignalspy.html), but that requires an explicit connection to a specific object and signal. The only other thing is the TestLib Framework, which has a [command-line option](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html#qtestlib-command-line-arguments) (`-vs`) that can output all the emitted signals during a test run. But that seems pretty far removed from what you're asking for.

Of course, you can use [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html) to list all the signals of a `QObject` and try to explicitly monitor everything. But that presupposes you can get a reference to all the objects you might be interested in (and that you can actually know in advance what they will be).

The only exception to the above, is for signals that are emitted via a [queued connection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). These signals, which are most commonly emitted across threads, are wrapped in an event and posted to the event-queue of the receiver's thread. It is possible to detect these kinds of signals by filtering on events of type `QEvent.MetaCall`.

However, the associated event objects are of type `QMetaCallEvent`, which is an internal Qt class which is not wrapped by PyQt. Normally, these objects would have `id()`, `sender()`, `signalId()` and `args()` methods. But in PyQt, all you'll get is a plain `QEvent`, and thus no information about the emitted signal will be available.

Even if `QMetaCallEvent` *was* available, though, the default connection type is *not* queued - and there is no way to globally reset the default for all signals.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the signal events you described are only used for queued connections. In this case events are sent to ensure slots are called after control is passed to the eventloop. Direct connections (wich you would use normally) are essentially just function calls and I doubt there is a way to intercept them without having access to the specific objects.